# Selecting a descendant of the created Rule in the Jquery Querybuilder afterAddRule event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, query-builder

This HTML is a snippet from a new rule that gets created when you click "Add Rule" in the Jquery Querybuilder.

```
  <div class="rule-header">
    <div class="btn-group pull-right rule-actions">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" data-delete="rule">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Delete
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="error-container" data-toggle="tooltip">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="rule-filter-container">
    <select class="form-control" name="ruleBuilder_rule_4_filter">
      <option value="-1">------</option>
      <option value="AccountType">AccountType: Account Type</option>
      <option value="ar_ledger">ar_ledger: AR Ledger</option>
         </select>
  </div>
  <div class="rule-operator-container"></div>
  <div class="rule-value-container"></div>
</div>
```

I am handling the addAfterRule event of the Querybuilder as follows and am trying to initialize a fuzzy search dropdown after the  box.  However, I can't seem to get a reference to the  box.  The $(rule).find() isn't working and I've tried all kinds of different selectors.  How do I get a reference to the  box so I can manipulate it?

```
 $('#ruleBuilder').queryBuilder({
                plugins: ['bt-tooltip-errors'],
                filters: filters,
                rules: jsonRules,
                operators:
                    [
                        'equal',
                        'not_equal',
                        'in',
                        'not_in',
                        'less',
                        'less_or_equal',
                        'greater',
                        'greater_or_equal',
                        'between',
                        'not_between',
                        'begins_with',
                        'not_begins_with',
                        'contains',
                        'not_contains',
                        'ends_with',
                        'not_ends_with',
                        //'is_not_empty',
                        'is_null',
                        'is_not_null',
                        { type: 'is_empty', nb_inputs: 0, multiple: false, apply_to: ['string'] },
                        { type: 'is_not_empty', nb_inputs: 0, multiple: false, apply_to: ['string'] }

                    ],
                lang: {
                    operators: {
                        is_empty: 'is empty',
                        is_not_empty: 'is not empty',
                        equal_boolean: 'equal'
                    }
                },
                sqlOperators: {
                    is_empty: { op: 'IS NULL' },
                    is_not_empty: { op: 'IS NOT NULL' },
                    equal_boolean: { op: 'equal' }
                }
            }).on('afterAddRule.queryBuilder', function (e, rule) {
                $(rule).find('.form-control').each(
                    function (index) {
                        $(this).after('<div id="fuzzSearch' + numFilters + 1 + '"><div id ="fuzzNameContainer"><span class="fuzzName"></span><span class="fuzzArrow"></span></div><div id="fuzzDropdownContainer"><input type="text" value="" class="fuzzMagicBox" placeholder="search.." /><span class="fuzzSearchIcon"></span><ul id="fuzzResults"></ul></div>');
                    });

                $(rule).find('.form-control').each(
                    function (index) {
                        $(this).fuzzyDropdown({ mainContainer: '#fuzzSearch' + numFilters + 1 });
                    });
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#build-query-defintion').queryBuilder({
            plugins: ['sortable', 'bt-tooltip-errors',
                'bt-checkbox',
                'invert',
                'not-group',
                'filter-description'],
            allow_empty: true,
            filters: result,
            rules: customFilters,
            icons: {
                add_group: 'fa fa-plus-square',
                add_rule: 'fa fa-plus-circle',
                remove_group: 'fa fa-minus-square',
                remove_rule: 'fa fa-minus-circle',
                error: 'fa fa-exclamation-triangle',
                sortable: 'fa fa-exclamation-triangle'
            }
        }).on('afterCreateRuleFilters.queryBuilder', function (e, rule) {
            rule.$el.find(QueryBuilder.selectors.rule_filter).selectpicker({
                liveSearch: true,
                //style:'width: 500px;',
            });
        });
```

Please include jquery query builder js, css
bootstrap js,cs
bootstrap selectpicker js,css
Hope this soultion will work for you.